# Ignore out of bound subscripts in tables

Tags: r, shiny

We are trying to ignore any entries that may be undefined at this point. Using example code below:

```
a <- c("Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Always","Always","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never")
b <- c("Maybe","Maybe","Yes","Maybe","Maybe","No","Yes","No")
results <- table(a,b)
results[c("Always","Occasionally"),]
```

Obviously that last line will currently crash.

Our results are coming in asyncronously, so we don't necessarily know if we've populated an index in the table yet. Is there a way to just ignore ones that are null? (So like "Occassionally" above) - do we need to construct this in a for loop instead of getting the subscripts using a collection?

Comment: It looks like you're using Shiny for this - have you considered using req() to blow up the stack if you get null values?

Comment: @Dubukay we don't actually want to blow up the stack. We would just want, for above example, to get the results with "Always" and ignore "Occassionally"

Comment: I see. Well, you could always do what I do with `table` and combine it with a vector containing one of each expected value, then subtract one before printing it. That way your "nulls" become actual numeric zeros and you don't have to worry about missing indices

Comment: I would use `%in%` to select only the values of `c("Always","Occasionally")` that occur in `a` . Like this `results[ unique(a) %in% c("Always","Occasionally"),]` then it will ignore using the options that don't occur in the data